# Series keeps unwanted terms

Tags: bugs, series-expansion

This expression doesn't simplify properly. I have this series.

```
In[33]:= temp2[[8]]

Out[33]= SeriesData[s, 0, {
 t[2] t[4], 0, Rational[3, 2] x[1] x[4]}, 0, 3, 1]
```

And I have this expresion of x in terms of u

```
In[38]:= replacement

Out[38]= {x[1] -> u[1] - 2 s u[1] u[2] - 2 s u[1] u[4],   x[2] -> u[2]
+ s u[2]^2, x[3] -> u[3] - 2 s u[3]^2 - 2 s u[3] u[4],   x[4] -> u[4] + s u[3] u[4] + 6 s u[4]^2,   x[5] -> u[5] + 5 s u[3] u[5]}
```

But when I use `temp[[8]]/.replacement` the series doesn't get truncated.

```
In[39]:= temp2[[8]] /. replacement

Out[39]= SeriesData[s, 0, {
 t[2] t[4], 0, 
  Rational[3, 2] (u[1] - 2 s u[1] u[2] - 2 s u[1] u[4]) (
   u[4] + s u[3] u[4] + 6 s u[4]^2)}, 0, 3, 1]
```

I don't know why the s inside the replacement is treated differently. `temp2` is actually a vector and all other entries are reduced appropiately. I don't what's happen for this entry in particular.

Here an example that works as I want

```
In[40] temp2[[7]]

Out[40]= SeriesData[s, 0, {
 t[2] t[5], (-3) x[2] + Rational[-1, 10] x[5], 
  Rational[9, 4] x[2]^2 + x[3] x[5] + Rational[-1, 168]
     x[5]^2}, 0, 3, 1]

In[41]:= temp2[[7]] /. replacement

Out[41]= SeriesData[s, 0, {
 t[2] t[5], (-3) u[2] + Rational[-1, 10] u[5], 
  Rational[1, 168] ((-126) u[2]^2 + 84 u[3] u[5] - u[5]^2)}, 0, 3, 1]
```

I have looked for a while and couldn't find the reason why this doesn't simplify properly.... I guess its something simple but I am a little puzzled. It's in the middle of a long calculation so, although I could erase the troubling terms by hand, I need to understand what's going to properly correct the whole calculation and ensure I don't get more similar errors

Thanks :)

Comment: Looks like a bug to me, I'd [report it to WR](http://www.wolfram.com/support/contact/email/).

Comment: hmmm ok. Didn't know there was some support form, will write there. good to know it :).

Comment: If you want to easily report to WRI you can click "Help" on the menu bar and select "GIve Feedback..." which will launch a browser for the WRI Support URL with several fileds already filled in.

Answer (score 1):

This works: `Normal`ize the series first, then do the replacement, then series-expand again:

```
S = temp2[[8]];
Series[Normal[S] /. replacement, {s, 0, 2}]
```

> SeriesData[s, 0, {t[2] t[4], 0, Rational[3, 2] u[1] u[4]}, 0, 3, 1]

You can extract the series parameters from `S==temp2[[8]]` directly, instead of hard-coding them:

```
Series[Normal[S] /. replacement, {s, S[[2]], (S[[5]] - 1)/S[[6]]}]
```

> (same result)

Comment: Thanks. That works. But I would like to know what's exactly the problem, because I am doing several operations with series and I don't want to get the same error somewhere else. I do not want to take Normal and Series neither because, I believe, it will make my program very slow.